# Editing word in skydrive with share function

Tags: microsoft-word, onedrive

Me and my buddy are using skydrive and we are sharing a word document. We're both editing the document in Microsoft Office 2013. When we update our documents, the comments that we write in the word are duplicated, each time we update. We're currently at 100 duplicates for one comment alone.

Does anyone know how to 'stop' that or is that a bug?
thank you for your answers

Comment: Are you editing the same copy of the document at the same time?

Comment: yes, but that's how it was supposed to be used, isn't it?

Comment: Just a guess as I can't check this out from here, but has either of you got change tracking switched on in Word 2013?

Comment: No, neither of us has track changes enabled...

Comment: Track changes is not identical with showing comments. That definitely sounds like a bug.What you could try doing is setting your tracking options to "Final" [the option that doesn't include the phrase 'Show Markup'].